# python list of strings readen from file to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've writing this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#ekadasi 2013
#sukhdev mohan
import datetime
import pickle
from time import strptime

def openfile(path, mode):
       return open(path, mode)

def closefile(obj):
       obj.close()

def retrivedata(pntr):
       date = {}
       linelst = []
       wordlst = []
       for line in pntr:
              for word in line.split():
                     wordlst.append(word)
              linelst.append(wordlst)
              wordlst = []
       return linelst


def dumpitall(obj, pntr):
       pickle.dump(obj, pntr)

def loaditall(srcpntr):
       return pickle.load(srcpntr)

date = datetime.date.today()
print "E K A D A S I  2 0 1 3 "
print "Today: %d - %d - %d" % (date.day, date.month, date.year)     

dates = {}
filepntr = openfile("ekadasi.txt", "r")
nlist = retrivedata(filepntr)
closefile(filepntr)
for nl in nlist:
       print nl
       temp = nl[0] + "-" + str(strptime(nl[1], '%B').tm_mon)
       print temp
       value = str(nl[2] + nl[3])
       dates = dict((temp, value))

print dates
```

I'm reading a file which has 4 colums: day month name(2 columns with a white space), as you can read i read it and then put in a list of list. What I'm aiming to do is to have a dictionary of type: day-number of month : name, but don't know why the dictionary isn't the same order as the file and list of list, example:
the first element is this
File: 08 January xyz asd
List: [['08', 'January', 'xyz', 'asd'], ... ]
key : 08-1
all as expected, but the dictionary as an other element as first and the first comes as second... how do I fix it? and is there any more good way to write this code or how i can optimise it?

thanks guys

Comment: You probably don't want to overwrite the `dates` dict with every iteration. And I'm not sure what your problem with the dictionary is - the order of elements? Normal dictionaries don't preserve insertion order, but there's an `OrderedDict` class in the `collections` module...

Comment: Yep My probem is the order as it is meant to preserve the dates... Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be something like this:

*As Uku Loskit mentioned it, use OrderedDict from collections. And also, you don't need to use that much for loops, you only need one. And use string.format() for readability and it is the main style in Python 3.*

```
import datetime
import collections
from time import strptime

date = datetime.date.today()
print "E K A D A S I  2 0 1 3 "
print "Today: {day} - {month} - {year}".format(
    day   = date.day,
    month = date.month,
    year  = date.year
)

dates = collections.OrderedDict()
with open('ekadasi.txt', 'r') as file_data:
    for line in file_data.readlines():
        if line:  # if line is not empty
            day, month, name1, name2 = line.split()
            temp = '{day}-{month}'.format(
                day = day,
                month = strptime(month, '%B').tm_mon
            )
            dates[temp] = str(name1 + name2)
print dates
```

Comment: Oh thanks :) I'm comming from C and C-like programming language so i asked if there was a better way to write it.

Comment: If you found my answer/solution useful, please upvote and accept it — if not, tell me how can I improve it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I forgot to do it: I've accepted your answer but i can't upvote because my reputation isn't enough :)

Answer (score 0):

There ordering of dictionary values is not guaranteed in any way. Use a [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer, and what about if i want to optimize it?

Comment: ok thanks, but may be i toldi t wrong: is there any better way to write the same code?